# PHP getting enter from textarea to send email

Tags: php, html

I created a form for users to key in recipient, subject name, and message to send mail via phpmailer. the problem i'm facing is with the textarea in my form.

I typed this into the textarea:

```
Hi john,
how's your day?

regards,
your best friend
```

but right now, this is showing in the email:

```
Hi john, how's your day? regards, your best friend
```

any ideas on how to format it to how the user enters in the text area? my current script is just

```
$body= $_POST["msg"];
```

i read that i should use nl2br but isnt that for output? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to turn on html email so it will recognize the line breaks

Comment: i'm using phpmailer and I've got $mail->isHTML(true); set. is that what you're talking about?

Comment: "i read that i should use nl2br but isnt that for output?" dud you test it- did it work ?

Comment: I tested it. it doesn't work. I think I might need something to sense the enter and give it a <br>. at the moment if I manually type any html, it works in the email. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you will need to do is add a break for each line.

```
$text = trim($_POST['textareaname']); // remove the last \n or whitespace character
$text = nl2br($text); // insert <br /> before \n
```

If you dont like that try this:(you may need to play with it.)

```
//trim off excess whitespace off the whole
$text = trim($_POST['textareaname']);

//explode all separate lines into an array
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);

//trim all lines contained in the array.
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

$str='';
//loop through the lines
foreach($textAr as $line){
$str .= $line."</br> ";
}
```

Comment: By the way, if i'd like to take it a step further doing something like the textarea in stackoverflow's ask a question, where should I start?

Comment: You mean for adding code formatting to a text area? Post another question and post the link here.

Comment: just posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930002/adding-text-formatting-to-textarea

Comment: Answered with what I use.