# Adding text formatting to textarea

Tags: php, html

I've got a textarea that accepts HTML and sends the message a user types to an email. Now I'd like to go a step further and make it easier for users with no HTML knowledge to further utilize the textarea.

How do I go about making a textarea with formatting at the top like the one in stackoverflow's ask a question?

EDIT
Thanks for all your great answers, but I've decided to go with **Hanoncs's** answer as that's the most straight forward. If anyone likes a better looking one, check out **BakerStreet's** answer.

Comment: you can try tinymce plugin http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below demo, you need to click on the text area before the buttons are enables.

```html
<div id="sample">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');
        new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
        new nicEditor({iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('area3');
        new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image']}).panelInstance('area4');
        new nicEditor({maxHeight : 100}).panelInstance('area5');
  });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <h4>
    Default (No Config Specified)
  </h4>
  <p>
    new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');
  </p>
  <textarea cols="50" id="area1">
</textarea>
  <h4>
    All Available Buttons {fullPanel : true}
  </h4>
  <p>
    new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
  </p>
  <textarea cols="60" id="area2">
Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea>
  <h4>
    Change Path to Icon File {iconsPath : 'path/to/nicEditorIcons.gif'}
  </h4>
  <p>
    new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('area3');
  </p>
  <textarea cols="50" id="area3">
</textarea>
  <h4>
    Customize the Panel Buttons/Select List
  </h4>
  <p>
    {buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript']}
  </p>
  <textarea cols="50" id="area4">
HTML content default in textarea
</textarea>
  <h4>
    Set a maximum expansion size (maxHeight)
  </h4>
  <p>
    {maxHeight : 100}
  </p>
  <textarea style="height: 100px;" cols="50" id="area5">
HTML content default in textarea
</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow uses markdown, which then gets converted to HTML. If you'd like to use markdown, here's a link to a decent tutorial:

[Markdown Tutorial](http://markdowntutorial.com/)

If, on the other hand, you want to edit straight HTML, my personal preference is using something like [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/), and since I use Bootstrap for just about everything I do, I like using a [bootstrappy version of wysihtml5](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg).

Best of luck!

Comment: There are tons of other HTML editors out there like ckeditor and such, but I find that they just don't look as nice. I like my projects to look great as well as work great.

Comment: Hi, I just downloaded the files from github. running the index.html file doesn't show me the editor though.. I've tried firefox, chrome and ie9. any ideas?

Comment: The index.html page requires bootstrap and jQuery, which are not included in the bootstrap-wysihtml5 repo. All you need to do is replace the bootstrap and jquery links with a valid CDN address, for example, replace <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link> with <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

Comment: I cant seem to find the links for wysihtml5x-toolbar.min.js, and handlebars.runtime.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) 
For how to use follow [this link](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/).

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

This sample shows how to automatically replace all  elements of a given class with a CKEditor instance.

To replace a  element, simply assign it the ckeditor class, as in the code below:

Note that other  attributes (like id or name) need to be adjusted to your document.

Comment: This needs to be a comment